# Cypher query to load a CSV file in Neo4j with a point data type property

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV file with 3 columns labeled, ID, latitude, longitude.  I want to load the CSV file into Neo4j and create nodes with the above properties.  The Location: property should be a point data type with latitude and longitude sub-properties.

CSV is:

```
ID,latitude,longitude
84,39.5990448,-104.75835419
etc...
```

So the start of the query would be:

```
LOAD CSV WITH Headers FROM 'http...' AS line
CREATE (:Node_Label {ID: line.ID, Location:????
```

How do I format the second property to import as a point type?

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple:

```
LOAD CSV WITH Headers FROM 'http...' AS line
CREATE (:Node_Label {
  ID: line.ID,
  Location: point({
    latitude: TOFLOAT(line.latitude),
    longitude: TOFLOAT(line.longitude)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks cybersam.  I just figured it out too.  I'll add one additional item, need to convert to float: latitude:toFloat(line.latitude).